# Capistrano Pointing to Old Release That No Longer Exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, asset-pipeline, sprockets

I have altered this question quite a bit based on changing circumstances.

My `deploy.rb` file:

```
set :rails_env "production"
set :branch,   "master"
set :keep_releases, 1

set :app_server, "ip address"
set :db_server,  "ip address"
server app_server, :app, :web
role :db, db_server, :primary => true

set :deploy_to, "/var/www"
set :user,      :cool_user

set :repository, "git account"
set :scm, "git"
set :scm_username, "my username"
set :scm_passphrase, "password"

ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true

after 'deploy:restart', 'deploy:cleanup'

after 'deploy:update', 'deploy:symlink'
```

When I run deploy everything looks fine in the console, no errors. But when I visit the site, it's pointing an old release that no longer exists in the server.

For example, when I visit the /pricing page I receive this error...

```
Unknown action

The action 'pricing' could not be found for DirectController
```

On another page, I receive this error...

```
Template is missing

Missing template layouts/anonymous
```

I have no idea how to point capistrano to the most recent version. Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

If I were to reboot the server then I receive this error.

```
Sprockets::FileNotFound in Home#index

couldn't find file 'angular'
  (in /var/www/releases/20140428003009/app/assets/javascripts/application.js:21)
```

**UPDATE:**

Comment: Did you add your SSH key to the `cool_user` user account on the server?

Comment: Do you mean there is a discrepancy between your running rails and the files? Restart the servers could work, maybe? But normally once running in production, everything is loaded beforehand: this means that if the files were changed, this would not reflect on the running rails servers at all. So either the bug already existed (and you fixed it and should restart), or this seems to be a _new_ routing error. The routing exists, but the action is not defined in the controller.

Comment: @nathanvda The rails that is currently running is pointing to an older version of the app. It will not update the code when I run deploy. Since the older released code no longer exists in the server (it's erased), it can't find the view files and thus produces an error.

Comment: @nathanvda I've updated my answer after I restarted the server.

Comment: You did do bundle install? Or how did you add the angular assets to your rails project?

Comment: @nathanvda Are you saying I would have to go into the server itself and run bundle install? I thought Capistrano would do that for you. I am using the angularjs gem for assets handling.

Comment: maybe your deploy log can help, run the deploy and copy here the output

Comment: please do a git stash on your local machine and push your code again to the git server as I think you git repo is not getting updated. And also run the following commands rake tmp:clear and rake assets:clean.

Comment: I've solved the problem by moving my angular_js gem out of the assets group to the general all-inclusive gem section. I also did an apache restart from within the server instead of rebooting from the hosting website. Thanks for all the help though!

Comment: @jason328 Could you please look at this question please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23338556/deployment-using-capistrano-gitlab-using-via-remote-cache i am also looking for an answer if you could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the problem by moving my angular_js gem out of the assets group and into the all group in my bundler. I also did an apache restart from within the server instead of rebooting from the hosting website. Thanks for all the help though!

Comment: Same thing happened to me, not exactly sure why but the restart did the trick for me!