# Deployment using Capistrano + Gitlab using via: remote_cache

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, git, rubygems, capistrano

I am using capistrano for the deployment of an PHP web application and we are having an internal gitlab server which is not accessible outside the network. I am trying to deploy using remote_cache as it is taking to much time if use it for copy. I have already checked [This](http://epochwolf.com/blog/2010/04/15/capistrano-use-git-repository-on-the-same-ser/) and [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293212/capistrano-git-repository-local-to-production-server) but not getting the desired result. I am trying the below code.

```
set :default_stage, "staging"
ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true
server "servername", :app, :web, :db, :primary => true
set :application, "appname"
set :scm, :git
set :repository, '.'
set :local_repository, "file://."
set :branch, "master"
default_run_options[:pty] = true
set :keep_releases, 2
set :user, 'username'
set :deploy_to, "/home/domain/public_html/test"    
set :copy_cache, true
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :copy_strategy, :export
set :use_sudo, false
set :copy_exclude, [".git", ".DS_Store", ".gitignore", ".gitmodules", "Capfile", "config/deploy.rb"]
```

What path to use for repository and local repository. Any suggestions how can I achieve this ?
EDIT : Can I use my local repo for the remote cache.

Comment: Does the deploy script is in the same path than the repository?

Comment: My script and my repo both present in Local.

Answer (score 2):

How do you mean use you local repository for remote_cache?

`:repository` is the url that the server being deployed to will use. So, if your Git server is running on the same server you are deploying to, you can set this to file:///path_to_repo

`:local_repository` is the url that you will use to connect to the repo from your local machine that you are running the capistrano script on. You only need to set this if you :repository is a local path and you are running capistrano from a different machine.

Example:

```
set :repository, "file:///home/git/my_repo"
set :local_repository, "http://server_address/my_repo"
```

However, if, for example, you repo is on Github, then you should only set `:repository` (DO NOT set `:local_repository`)

```
set :repository, "git@github.com/your_account/your_repo.git"
```

Capistrano automatically creates a directory for keeping it's clone of the repo when using remote_cache deployment (shared/cached-copy).

Do you get an error when you run the script?

Comment: if you use set :repository to "." it will take your local copy.

Comment: If you say set :repository, "file:///home/git/my_repo"
set :local_repository, "http://server_address/my_repo" will this be the path of my repo or it should be used as it is?

Comment: Is your Git repo on the same server as the server you are deploying *to* (i.e. your web server)?

Comment: I have tried using my path was still giving me same does not exist. I did a git clone from my gitlab server. Again I like to mention my gitlab server is in accessible to LAN.

Comment: But it is on a different server on the LAN, yes? In which case, you need to set :repository to the address from which you would clone. DO NOT set :local_repository. Capistrano will do it's own magic to store a local version for deploying with remote_cache

Comment: when I set the repo path to my internal git server it gives me the following error  [54.252.191.11 :: out] ssh: Could not resolve hostname "servername": Name or service not known
 ** fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
 ** 
 ** Please make sure you have the correct access rights
 ** and the repository exists.

Comment: I'm assuming you have edited the actual servername? Can you ssh onto your server that you are deploying to as the user that the capistrano script is running as and clone the Git repo? By default it will use the username you are logged onto your local machine as. If not, you will need to set the :user variable in you config to the correct user on your remote server

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51890/discussion-between-arihant-godha-and-dave-kirk)